# Applying Economics Ph.D/Agricultural/Applied Economics Ph.D programs with low GRE

Tags: graduate-admissions, gre, economics

I am trying to apply for Ph.D. programs in either economics or agricultural/applied economics. I believe the other aspects of my application are good. I have high GPAs in both undergraduate and graduate education. I have 3 years of research experiences working at the think-tank. And, I have one publication related to my research interest. My GRE quant score is only 77th percentile. I am now trying to apply a school. The school's admission website describes that there is no minimum GRE requirement but those I am competing will have GRE quant 85th percentile or above. Can some people suggest me if I should still apply that school? I am afraid of my application being filtered out. Your thoughts would be highly appreciated. Thanks.